# Is the wifi at TPE airport in Terminal 1 or 2 fast and robust enough to video call for 2 hours?

Tags: airports, internet, wifi, taipei, tpe

Is the wifi network at TPE airport in Terminal 1 or 2 fast and robust enough to use a videoconference program (e.g. Skype) for two hours during a layover?

---

Abbreviations:

- TPE = [Taiwan Taoyuan International Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taoyuan_International_Airport)

Comment: Is there a business center with a good internet feed at the airport that you could use ?

Comment: @Max I don't know, but if there is one that could be a good option indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks [like there is a service iTaiwan Wi-Fi which aims to provide 1Mbps](https://itaiwan.gov.tw/en/faq.php) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190913004055/https://itaiwan.gov.tw/en/faq.php)), which is more than enough for video calling, but as ckx mentioned, relying on it could be iffy.  But yes, theoretically, it's feasible.

The airport itself, according to [a collection of airport speed tests](https://www.alexi.xyz/blog/airport-wifi-speed-test) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190913010724/https://www.alexi.xyz/blog/airport-wifi-speed-test)):

> TPE airport - located in Taiwan - offers totally free wifi to
>   passenger. The passenger just connects to a wifi network called
>   “Airport Free WiFi” and the internet becomes available right away.
>
> Here is the result of “Airport Free WiFi” speed test:
>
> ```
> Local Internet Speed (within Taiwan)
>
>     Download: 17.90 Mbps
>
>     Upload: 16.91 Mbps
>
>     Ping: 22 ms
>
>     Server Location: Taoyuan, Taiwan
>
>     Tested Date: 9/23/2017
>
> International Internet Speed
>
>     Download: 8.83 Mbps
>
>     Upload: 14.10 Mbps
>
>     Ping: 104 ms
>
>     Server Location: Bangkok, Thailand
>
>     Tested Date: 9/23/2017
> ```

also, plenty fast.

Comment: Thanks, the linked page says "you can activate your iTaiwan account online by using the airport’s free WiFi connection or any iTaiwan hotspots" which makes me wonder whether the airport’s free WiFi connection is independent from the iTaiwan hotspot network.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt looks like you're  right, I've found more info and updated.

Answer (score 2):

In general, relying on a single service for something important is very likely to end up in tears. What if it has an outage...? What if a jerk decides to watch Netflix on the same AP you are on? I would rather pick up a SIM card from eBay before leaving -- even just as a backup.

Comment: Agreed, having a backup option is best, I am just trying to figure out the expected wifi quality. I can move around in the airport if one AP is busier than typical.